# how to sum multiple rows with same id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Lets say I have following table:

```
id | name | no 
--------------
1  |  A   | 10
1  |  A   | 20
1  |  A   | 40
2  |  B   | 20
2  |  B   | 20
```

And I want to perform a select query in SQL server which sums the value of "no" field which have same id.
Result should look like this,

```
id | name | no 
--------------
1  |  A   | 70
2  |  B   | 40
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I'm sure typing this question took longer than the research needs to take.

Comment: We absolutely do not need yet another question about such a basic feature of SQL, which demonstrates no background research whatsoever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are so many duplicates it isn't even funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple `GROUP BY` and `SUM` should work.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SUM([NO]) 
FROM Your_TableName
GROUP BY ID, NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Use SUM and GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

`SELECT ID,NAME, SUM(NO) AS TOTAL_NO  FROM TBL_NAME GROUP BY ID, NAME`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *, SUM(no) AS no From TABLE_NAME GROUP BY name
```

This will return the same table by summing up the `no` column of the same `name` column.